# Intent action for new network added (Android)

Tags: android, wifi

WiFiManager has an addNetwork(wifiConfiguration) method which allows to programmatically add a new network. This is also performed behind the scenes by the system whenever the user/native-manager tries to connect to a new access point and I want to listen to this event.

I tried:

```
IntentFilter myStateChanged = new IntentFilter();       
myStateChanged.addAction( WifiManager.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION );
ctx.registerReceiver(myStateChgRcvr, myStateChanged);
```

But in my broadcast receiver what do I do with the intent object to get the desired info? I want to ascertain that this is indeed a case of a new network profile added and I want to get that network's info:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myStateChgRcvr = new BroadcastReceiver() {        
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {          
        i.getParcelableExtra(...)); //???
    }
};
```

Many thanks,

Spitzer

Answer (score 0):

> But in my broadcast receiver what do I do with the intent object to get the desired info?

Nothing. There are no documented `Intent` extras on that `Intent`.

> I want to ascertain that this is indeed a case of a new network profile added and I want to get that network's info:

Call `getConfiguredNetworks()` on `WifiManager` and see if anything has changed, I guess.

Comment: Calling getConfiguredNetworks() and checking for changes will cost in performance. Do you reckon listening to WifiManager.NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION would minimize the number of times I would need to do it or is there a better action to listen to?

Comment: @Spitzer: "Calling getConfiguredNetworks() and checking for changes will cost in performance" -- and your proof of this is... what exactly? "is there a better action to listen to?" -- not that I am aware of.

Comment: Great, I'll do it that way. I just wasn't sure what else causes NETWORK_IDS_CHANGED_ACTION to trigger an event and I didn't want to run a potentially heavy request every time a network scan (or anything of that sort) is made. I tried to test it and I think it triggers only when a network is added or removed, is that true?  In any case, thanks a lot for the quick response :)

Comment: @Spitzer: I haven't use that action, but from the docs I would assume that it is only invoked on an added/removed network, just as I would assume that `getConfiguredNetworks()` is fairly cheap (either in-RAM or, at worst, on-flash database).